# NLog not writing header on daily rollover

Tags: nlog

Nlog isn't writing the header when rolling over log file each day in my Windows service. If the log file doesn't exist it writes the header, and if the archiveEvery="Minute" then the header is written to the new log file. This is the nlog config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="trace"
      internalLogFile="C:\Log\InnerLog.txt"
      throwExceptions="true">

  <variable name="AppName" value="Test Service" />

  <targets>
    <target
      name="logfile"
      xsi:type="File"
      fileName="C:\Log\smgresp${date:format=MM-dd-yyyy}.log"
      layout="${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} ${message}"
      archiveEvery="Day"
      maxArchiveFiles="30"
      header="${AppName} version ${assembly-version}"
    />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Is this a bug? I'm working around it by checking in my code for the first log entry for a day and logging the header equivalent as an Info entry.

Comment: Remember not to use `throwExceptions="true"` unless as last resort, when troubleshooting why NLog.config will not load properly. It is intended for unit-testing, and will cause unwanted behavior in production environment.

Comment: Thanks - I've removed that from the config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either use archive mode with dynamic filename (without `archiveEvery`):

```
<target
  name="logfile"
  xsi:type="File"
  fileName="C:\Log\smgresp${date:format=MM-dd-yyyy}.log"
  layout="${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} ${message}"
  maxArchiveFiles="30"
  header="${AppName} version ${assembly-version}"
/>
```

Or else using archive mode with static filename (with `archiveEvery` and `archiveFileName`):

```
<target
  name="logfile"
  xsi:type="File"
  layout="${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} ${message}"
  fileName="C:\Log\smgresp.log"
  archiveFileName="C:\Log\smgresp.{#}.txt"
  archiveEvery="Day"
  maxArchiveFiles="30"
  header="${AppName} version ${assembly-version}"
/>
```

See also:

- [Examples of using static archive mode in NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/FileTarget-Archive-Examples)
- [Description of static and dynamic archive mode in NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3807#issuecomment-587661413)
- [History of static and dynamic archive mode in NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/4105#issuecomment-685952654)

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem. I stayed with dynamic and removed the `archiveEvery` attribute - didn't realized that dynamic mode would automatically create the file when the date changed.